# Carrierwave does not fallback to default_url even if file is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm using `carrierwave (0.10.0)` with Fog for S3 uploads.
Implementing simple uploader:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*_args)
    "#{Rails.configuration.cdn_url}/no-image.png"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

and mount it here

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

When Im trying to set remote image even if no image is presented it doesn't fallback to `default_url` and simulates generation of file in S3 which is actually not there.

Example:

```
u = User.find('1234567')
u.remote_avatar_url = 'http://non-existing-url.com/avatar.jpg'
u.save!
```

And when I access after reloading document

```
u.reload
u.avatar.url # output https://ourcdn.url/somebucket/avatar.jpg
```

But when access it in the browser it's showing 404.
Any ideas?

Comment: well carrierwave shows default url when your database has no value for the image columns for any rows. Otherwise not. In your case, you are saving a value to the image column and saves it, and that cancelling the default url rule.